# Grupo de radiobutton - ASP.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy realizando mi proyecto en `**MVC 5**` y deseo implementar un grupo de `Radiobutton` y que al seleccionar uno el otro se desactive para poder mantener solo un `check` activo.

Tengo mi siguiente código:

```
 bool rbMerma = false;
 bool rbNConforme = false;

  <div class="row intercaladoBottom">
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Nu_secu, "Tipo Producción", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-4" })
     @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RbMerma, true) Yes
     @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RbNConforme, false) No
  </div>
```

Al momento de seleccionar los 2 se activan ambos, como se debe hacer en estos casos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los 2 `RadioButtons` deben de tener el mismo `name` para que **`Razor`** los tome como un `button group`

```
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RbNConforme, true) Yes
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RbNConforme, false) No
```